# How to put parameters in sql query builder with LIKE %..% sql

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

So i'm using a SQLiteQueryBuilder in this form.

```
private static final String broadSearchSelection =
        ArticleEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " LIKE  % ? %   OR " +
                ArticleEntry.COLUMN_SOURCE + " LIKE  % ? %  OR " +
                ArticleEntry.COLUMN_SUMMARY + " LIKE  % ? %  OR "  +
                CategoryEntry.COLUMN_DISPLAY_CATEGORY_NAME + " LIKE % ? % ";
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't allow me to run the program in this form. Neither with LIKE " % ? % ", nor LIKE ' % ? % ' , nor with \" nor with \'. Can you guyz tell me how to write the builder such that it reconizes my parameters? I'm runnig it with the code:

```
 articleByCategoryQueryBuilder.query(mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE expects a single string.
The `%` must be inside the string, but `?` is not a literal character and must be outside:

```
COLUMN_XXX + " LIKE '%' || ? || '%' " + ...
```